# how to display math equations in block with markdown

Tags: markdown, equations

In **markdown** quick reference, we know that one can display plain code in blocks by enclosing the code in ```.  I wonder if there is a simple way to display math equations in block too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Vanilla Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) and [Markdown Extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/) don't support mathematics. However, [kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#math-blocks) and [MultiMarkdown](https://github.com/fletcher/MultiMarkdown/wiki/MultiMarkdown-Syntax-Guide#wiki-math-support) do very easily, and there's [an extension for PHP Markdown Extra](https://github.com/drdrang/php-markdown-extra-math) that you can use. The syntax is different for each, so it depends on which you're using.

In short, in kramdown, use `$$ double dollar signs $$`, and in MultiMarkdown or the PHP Markdown Extra Math extension, use `\[ LaTeX-style brackets \]` for display and `\(LaTeX-style parentheses\)` for inline mathematics.