# Adding mathjax/katex math inside a div class in markdown/html

Tags: html, css, markdown, mathjax, katex

How do I add `$E=mc^2$` math to be rendered with mathjax/katex inside a CSS class? I am trying to use this inside the following classes in markdown:

```
.theorem {
display: block;
font-style: italic;
}
.theorem:before {
content: "Theorem. ";
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
}
.theorem[text]:before {
content: "Theorem (" attr(text) ") ";
}
```

e.g.

```
<div class="theorem" data-text="Foo"> bar is $\alpha = \beta$.
</div>
```

But it fails to render the example provided.

EDIT: turns out, for math in `$...$` to be rendered inside the `<div>` class, a line has to be skipped.
e.g.

```
<div class="theorem" data-text="Foo">

Given $a, b$:
$$a = b$$
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, cool. You've told us what you want to do and what you've tried. What's the problem? How is this failing to do what you want? Please read [ask].

Comment: Turns out for the math to be rendered by mathjax/katex, inside a <div> class, you have to skip a line before adding `$...$`.

Comment: I had a similar problem and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111421/how-to-display-math-equations-in-block-with-markdown) might be useful.